# Sync comment data

Tags: comments, facebook

I have a site that used Facebook comments for a period of time and then removed them for native WP comments. I was able to write a function that grabbed all the comments and re-inserted them into the WP database (as FB comments do not store in WP). However, Facebook's OpenGraph API does not provide email addresses (which I understand).

So what I want to accomplish is the following:

1. Query the comment table for a specific name using the `comment_author`
2. Pull all comments by that name
3. If there is an email address present in one comment array, copy it over to the one that is missing

I have accomplished #1 and #2, but I'm at a loss for #3. Any ideas?

Answer (score 2):

After some more thought, I got it figured out. It involves multiple functions to go through each step of the process, but here it is:

https://gist.github.com/4355955

Answer (score 0):

I don't know the schema, but if you're doing it for one specific author at a time, something along the lines of:

```
$foo = $db->Execute("SELECT DISTINCT(email) FROM comments WHERE comment_author = ? AND email <> ''",$authorname);
if ($foo->count > 0) {
  $db->Execute("UPDATE comments SET email = ? WHERE comment_author = ? AND email <> ''",$foo[0],$authorname);
}
```

Apologies for assuming some random, generic db object/interface....